# Suffix array using qsort() and strcmp

Tags: arrays, c, qsort, suffix

I have the following code to create a sorted suffix array but there is simply no output. I run the program and it halts for 1-2secs and then exits.

The code is based off the c++ answer on the following website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-1-introduction/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct suffix
{
    int index; 
    char *suff;
};

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct suffix *a1 = a;
    const struct suffix *b1 = b;  
    return strcmp(a1->suff, b1->suff) < 0? 1 : 0;
}

int *buildSuffixArray(char *txt, int n)
{
    struct suffix suffixes[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        suffixes[i].index = i;
        suffixes[i].suff = (txt+i);
    }

    qsort(suffixes, n, sizeof(int), cmp);

    int *suffixArr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        suffixArr[i] = suffixes[i].index;
    }

    return suffixArr;
}

void printArr(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char txt[] = "banana";
    int n = strlen(txt);
    int *suffixArr = buildSuffixArray(txt, n);
    printf("following is suffix array for %s\n", txt);
    printArr(suffixArr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Since there is no output, I assume that the problem is within the 'buildSuffixArray' function, specifically with qsort. I have tried fixing it but had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `qsort(suffixes, n, sizeof(int), cmp);` should be `qsort(suffixes, n, sizeof suffixes[0], cmp);`

Comment: The `cmp()` function must return a negative, zero or positive value depending on whether the first argument sorts before, equal to or after the second value.  Your `cmp()` function returns only `1` or `0`.  This will screw up any sorting.  If the values compared are A and B and they are not equal, then `cmp(A, B)` must return a value of the opposite sign to `cmp(B, A)`, but your code does not.  It would be sufficient to return the value from `strcmp()`.  Note that the magnitude of the result does not matter — only the sign of the result.

Comment: Fyi, you don't need a struct to do this. A pointer array and some pointer math based on the base address of your input string will do it for you and grant the same results. It may even make it overall-clearer what you're really doing (sorting a raft of suffix strings based on pointers, all peeking into the same string buffer).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It seems that the return value from `strcmp()` should be negated before returning it in this case, i.e. change `return strcmp(a1->suff, b1->suff) < 0? 1 : 0;` to `return -strcmp(a1->suff, b1->suff);`. Alternatively, the arguments of `strcmp` could be swapped to negate the result: `return strcmp(b1->suff, a1->suff);`.

Comment: ds778104,  Tip: `int *suffixArr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));` --> `int *suffixArr = malloc(sizeof suffixArr[0] * n);`.  No cast,  size to object, not type, sizeof first.

Comment: @IanAbbott: If, as seems plausible but is not stated, the requirement is for a sort in descending alphabetic order, then yes, you're right — the return value from `strcmp()` needs to be negated.  It would have been helpful if the question was an [MCVE] and had included the desired output as well as the actual output.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for that answer. I am trying to implement this into a dictionary.txt file and am having no luck. I have read the file into a buffer and am trying to implement the above code but it isnt working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It looked like the code was trying to sort in descending order (based on returning 1 when a<b), but in the linked-to problem it looks like it should be sorting in ascending order. The linked-to C++ code uses `std::sort()` which has different rules than `qsort()` for the comparison function (return `true` if first argument less than second argument). So a comparison function for C++ `std::sort()` is no good for C `qsort()`. OP just (more or less) copied the comparison function from the C++ code without adapting it properly for use with `qsort()`.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments in the question from **Weather Vane** and **Jonathan Leffler**:

1. OP is passing the wrong element size to `qsort()`. `qsort(suffixes, n, sizeof(int), cmp);` should be `qsort(suffixes, n, sizeof suffixes[0], cmp);`. (**Weather Vane**).
2. The `cmp` function must return a negative value if the first argument sorts before the second argument, zero if they sort equal, or a positive value if the first argument sorts after the second argument. OP's `cmp` function returns 1 if the first argument is less than the second argument, otherwise 0. This will screw up any sorting by `qsort()`. (**Jonathan Leffler**)

It appears that the `cmp` function written by OP was based on the C++ code from [Suffix Array | Set 1 (Introduction)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-1-introduction/). In particular, OP's `return strcmp(a1->suff, b1->suff) < 0? 1 : 0;` is based on the similar `return strcmp(a.suff, b.suff) < 0? 1 : 0;` in the C++ code. The problem is that the C++ code uses `std::sort()`, not `qsort()` and the rules for the return value of the comparison functions are different.

As **Jonathan Leffler** points out, it would be sufficient for OP's `cmp` function to return the value from `strcmp()` directly:

```
    return strcmp(a->suff, b->suff);
```

OP's `printArr()` function prints the integers in the array with no separation between each number. The correction is trivial.